# Is it good practice to return from inside a loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, return

When I write any validation function, I write code as seen below

Approach 1.

```
def func():
    for section in sections:
        if section.has_timetable():
            return True
    return False
```

But lately I am thinking is it good practice to exit a function like that? will there be any consequences following this approach, if yes should follow the approach 2?

Approach 2

```
def func():
    has_timetable = False
    for section in sections:
        if section.has_timetable():
            has_timetable = True
            break
    return has_timetable
```

Comment: Yes, returning early is normally preferred rather than having to finish iterating over the entire collection when it's not needed, unless there's something else going on that warrants a complete iteration (finding the minimum/maximum value, etc.)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add break, But is it ok to break the loop by returning?

Comment: Oh, well if you're going to break out of the loop and immediately return, just return!

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: Also possible: `any(s.has_timetable() for s in sections)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's ok! Of course you have to make sure you actually get the result you are looking for, but nothing bad happens if you return inside a loop. Return just passes you the result and it's actually common to return some value in a loop. In your case it's a boolean, so you return true (or you can see it as a 1) or false( as a 0)

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic way of writing this would look like

```
def has_timetable(sections):
    for section in sections:
        if section.has_timetable():
            result = True
            break
    else:
        result = False
    return result
```

But whether you `break` and then return or *return early* is a matter of taste; at least in this case. This function is easy to read and comprehend, so, more than one `return` does no harm. In longer functions with multiple returns, it might be hard to get all the exit points.

I would go for *what is better readable for you*.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1 is more efficient compared to Approach 2 as it is returning as soon as it finds a matching condition. However, as far as good practice is concerned, I feel it is better to have a single return statement. For example, if you have multiple conditions to check, there will be multiple return statements and this can make debugging difficult (imagine you want to put a breakpoint in your code to check return value before function returns. You will end up putting breakpoint at every return statement.). To avoid this, you can modify your Approach 2 code little bit to make it more efficient as follows:

```
 def func():
    has_timetable = False
    for section in sections:
        if section.has_timetable():
            has_timetable = True
            break
    return has_timetable
```

Thus, you can have multiple `break` statements and only one `return` statement. While debugging, you have to put only one breakpoint at the `return` statement.